# UIControl memory leak

Tags: ios, swift, memory-leaks, uicontrol

I usually set up `UIImageView` and `UITextField` etc like the example below. However I'm getting a memory leak in the example below and I'm not sure why.

**If I use the standard set up with**

```
var buttonImageView: UIImageView!
```

and set up the `buttonImageView` within the init method the leak goes away

**OR**

with the example below if I make it `lazy` the leak also goes away

**Example**

```
class BasicButton: UIControl {

    // Cause of leak
    var buttonImageView: UIImageView = {
        let logoView = UIImageView()
        logoView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        logoView.tintColor = UIColor.blue
        logoView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        logoView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        return logoView
    }()

    init(image: UIImage) {
        self.init()
        buttonImageView.image = image
        setupView()
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    private func setupView() {
        addSubview(buttonImageView)
        setupLayout()
    }

    private func setupLayout() {
        translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            buttonImageView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerXAnchor),
            buttonImageView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerYAnchor),
            buttonImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 80),
            buttonImageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 80)
        ])
    }
}
```

Comment: In instruments... but I found the cause. Will post answer.

Comment: Great. BTW, if you won’t take offense, I did have some unrelated observations: https://gist.github.com/robertmryan/687ae5e23672bea2c9331f94992ec5a0

Comment: I never take offense - I want to learn from experts like yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I wasn't calling `super`. The correct way to init the `UIControl` would be the following:

```
init(image: UIImage) {
    // Fixes Leak
    super.init(frame:CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100))
    // Wrong init was called causing leak
    // self.init()

    buttonImageView.image = image
    setupView()
}
```

However, the code would still compile and run, but causing a leak in the process. If someone could elaborate on why this occurs it would be appreciated.